# OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'plotting.backend'"

Tags: python

I'm trying to run an assignment but got stuck at the first step:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

pd.set_option('plotting.backend', 'pandas_bokeh')
```

I got an error message: OptionError: "No such keys(s): 'plotting.backend'"

Does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks in advance!